# Malicious OT from 'Efficient Secure Two Party Protocols' --- defining the simulators

Tags: provable-security, oblivious-transfer

I am looking at Protocol 7.5.1 in Hazay and Lindell's Efficient Secure Two Party Protocols, it can found [here](http://www.di.univr.it/documenti/Avviso/all/all459711.pdf)
(p 201).

A similar protocol is proven secure in Section 7.4 (p190) and the proof is given in a good level of detail. For Protocol 7.5.1 however the proof given is only short. References are given to where the protocol is taken from, but again there I am struggling see a detailed proof.

In particular I am struggling to write down the exact Simulators that are needed to prove security in the malicious setting for each party. I would like to be able to see a proof that is similar in detail to Protocol 7.4.1 in the previous section. For one party we need to reduce the the DDH problem, and the other we can show the real and ideal views are equal...I think?

Thanks in advance.